# Insert figure/image to Excel from MATLAB

Tags: excel, matlab, excel-addins, matlab-compiler

I'm building my own Excel Add-in using MATLAB Library Compiler.
I'm trying to build a function/add-in which takes two columns of data and plots it on a graph.
I can not figure out how to insert the figure from the MATLAB function into Excel.

**Example**

---

We have a MATLAB function called plot2D, which looks like this:

```
function [fig] = plot2D(DataX,DataY)
    fig = figure;
    plot(DataX, DataY,'r--');
end
```

We now use MATLAB Library Compiler and compile it into a *xla*-file and import it into Excel.
What I want is whenever I use this add-in it should generate a graph inside the current Excel sheet, given two data entries.

[image: Plot2D function]

Now this doesn't work since Excel can't read the datatype *figure* of MATLAB.
But how would I go about this? Any suggestions?
Thank you.

Comment: Are u looking https://www.mathworks.com/help/exlink/mlgetfigure.html ?

Comment: Maybe! How do I use this? Is it part of any particular library?

Comment: try out the example code.. it should work /(^_^)

Comment: btw.. sorry I'm not familiar to xla conversion..does exporting the fig to jpeg an option? (just suggesting alternatives)

Comment: Whenever I use MLGetFigure I receive an error. I have an active figure running in Matlab. The error doesn't though, only the Windows sound...